# Disable data table fixed header for materialize responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, materialize, fixed-header-tables

I am using data table with fixed header functionality using materialize framework. This is working fine for web view but for mob and tab view I am using default materialize datatable design for that I need to disable fixed header functionality.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8th4dte/26/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="tblContainer" class="material-table z-depth-3 hoverable">
  <table id="myTable" class="responsive-table highlight"></table>
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

I tried using "**responsive: true**" also but not working. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data2 = {
    "results": [{
        "Name": "test1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      },
      {
        "Name": "test 1",
        "Age": "23",
        "Amount": "234944",
        "Profit": "722636",
        "Loss": "6346326",
        "Address": "My test Address"
      }
    ]
  };


  $('#myTable').dataTable({
    data: data2.results,
    "order": [],
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    columns: [{
        data: 'Name',
        title: "Name"
      },
      {
        data: 'Amount',
        title: "Amount"
      },
      {
        data: 'Profit',
        title: "Profit"
      },
      {
        data: 'Loss',
        title: "Loss"
      },
      {
        data: 'Age',
        title: "Age"
      },
      {
        data: 'Address',
        title: "Address"
      },
      {
        data: 'Loss',
        title: "Loss"
      },
      {
        data: 'Age',
        title: "Age"
      },
      {
        data: 'Address',
        title: "Address"
      }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "200px",
        "targets": [0]
      },
      {
        "width": "100px",
        "targets": [1]
      },
      {
        "width": "100px",
        "targets": [2]
      },
      {
        "width": "100px",
        "targets": [3, 6]
      },
      {
        "width": "100px",
        "targets": [4, 7]
      },
      {
        "width": "200px",
        "targets": [5, 8]
      }
    ],
    "fixedHeader": {
      header: true
    },
    "responsive": true
  });

});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedHeader.disable()

Comment: I read this document also. But how to disable fixed hider only for responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change the @media helps you:

```
@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
 table.material-table thead tr th{
  width: auto !important;
 }
 table.material-table thead{
  min-width: 20% !important;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable({
"fixedHeader": { 
      "header": false, 
      "footer": false 
      }
});
```